# Does dispatch_async() and similar provide memory fences?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, memory-fences

When I run a block on any queue via `dispatch_async` or similar, does GCD provide thread fences around the block invocation? I would assume it does, but the documentation gives no hint one way or the other as far as I can tell.

Comment: What exactly do you think might not be working as you think it should?

Comment: @gnasher729 Nothing in particular, I'm just wondering if I need to put my own memory fences down or if GCD already employs them. This is more of a conceptual question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From an email thread on the Cocoa-Dev mailing list, Greg Parker (one of Apple's runtime engineers) [replied to a question of mine](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/Dec/msg00140.html):

> > [S]ince the use of GCD hasn't brought catastrophe down on all of our heads, I assume that dispatch_async() and the like do provide such memory barriers.  Likewise, NSOperationQueue, -performSelector:onThread:..., and the like must also.  Is that right?
>
> I would expect that any multiprocessing primitive that does not provide sufficient memory barriers for some uses would document that fact loudly. dispatch_once()'s storage is one documented example of missing barriers. Some of the OSAtomic functions are another example. But pretty much everything heavier-weight than that ought to provide complete memory barriers for any clients.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I started going through the dispatch source code, but it's not entirely straightforward with its shoe-horned vtable usage and macros everywhere.